Why having a global convex upper bound is considered as an advantage for the convex-concave procedure?
I am reading this paper "Variations and extension of the convex–concave procedure" and on page 5/25, second paragraph, the authors state that "Another advantage of CCP is that the over estimators ${f_i}\left( x \right) - {\hat g_i}\left( {x;{x_k}} \right)$ are global."
For the case of minimizing $x^4-x^2$, I have seen that the CCP can construct the following convex overestimator $x^4-x^2 \le x^4 - (2xx_0-x_0^2)$. Furthermore, the inequality is indeed true for all real $x_0,x$ because it could be reduce to $-(x-x_0)^2 \le 0$.
I dont understand the advantage of being global in this case. Especially advantage in term of what criteria ? Does it reduce the burden of doing something or does it make the algorithm converge faster.
Since I am an engineer would you kindly help me understand this issue with some example or some analogy ?
Thank you for you enthusiasm !

As each $g_i$ is a convex function, then the linear approximation ${\hat g_i}\left( {x;{x_k}}\right)$ of $g_i$ at point $x_k$ used in the paper becomes a global under estimator for $g_i$, so  ${f_i}\left( x \right) - {\hat g_i}\left( {x;{x_k}} \right)$ is a global over estimator for $f_i-g_i$, that is,
$$\color{blue}{{f_i}\left( x \right) - {\hat g_i}\left( {x;{x_k}} \right)\ge {f_i}\left( x \right) -  g_i( x), \,\forall x\in \mathbb R}.$$
This has two advantages described below.
Feasibility Advantage
This helps us to safely approximate the solution space at each iteration due to the following implication:
$${f_i}\left( x \right) - {\hat g_i}\left( {x;{x_k}} \right) \le 0 \Rightarrow {f_i}\left( x \right) - {f_i}\left( x \right) \le 0$$
and let us be sure that each next point $x_{k+1}$ obtained by Algorithm 1  in each iteration is again a feasible solution of the original problem.
Note that a main issue with SQP methods applied to general nonlinear programming models is that points that satisfy the approximated constraints used at each iteration are not necessarily feasible solutions of the original problem. In the above paper, the convex-concave substructure of the model is used in Algorithm 1 to manage this issue nicely.
Convergence Advantage
To prove that the sequence of objective function values $$v_k=f_0(x_k)-g_0(x_k), k=0,1,\dots$$ for points $x_k, k=0,1,\dots$ generated by Algorithm 1  converges, the property that ${f_0}\left( x \right) - {\hat g_0}\left( {x;{x_k}} \right)$ is a global over estimator for $f_0-g_0$ is again used to show the right inequality in
$$v_k\ge {f_0}\left( x_{k+1} \right) - {\hat g_0}\left( {x_{k+1};{x_k}} \right)\color{blue}{\ge} v_{k+1}$$
given in page 266.
Remark: When the problem is bounded, this sequence surely converges to a finite number, but it may converge to $-\infty$ if the problem is unbounded. However, the bad news is that the limit point of the sequence $x_k, k=0,1,\dots$ is proven to be a critical point, not necessarily a local minimum. For example, for function $x^4 -x ^2$, if we start from $x_0=0$, Algorithm 1 terminates at $x_1=0$ in one iteration, which is a local maximum of the function (see the example given in page 266).

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

So for a difference of convex decomposition f=g-h, does it require g and h to be convex everywhere ? All of my decision variable is none negative so could I use a DC decomposition in which g and h is convex on the positive orthant ?

@TuongNguyenMinh If the constraints $x_i\ge0,i=1,\dots,n$ are considered explicitly in the model, yes you can safely use the algorithm as it never visits any point outside the positive orthant.

are there any case when we actually arrive at the minimum instead of the maximum ?

@TuongNguyenMinh I need to check. It may be the case when the objective is convex. Meanwhile you may include your optimization model in the OP or make it available in a link.

Hmm what if the objective is not con vex but are sure to be monoticity. It always decrease.

@TuongNguyenMinh I checked it again but could not find any useful results.  To use the above algorithm, just run it for many different start points, and select the best among the converging solutions.

Thank you very much !!!!

I think "global" here refers to the fact that the iterates preserve feasibility no matter how far they go. The linearized constrains are overestimates of the original ones because the linearization of any convex function at any given point stays under the curve of the convex function globally. That is for any convex function $g_i$ it holds that $\hat{g}_i(x,x_k) \le g_i(x)$ for all $x$ and $x_k$. After expanding the linearized constraint this way
$$
0 \ge f_i(x) - \hat{g}_i(x;x_k) = f_i(x) - g_i(x) + \underbrace{g_i(x) - \hat{g}_i(x;x_k)}_{\ge 0} .
$$
you can see that $x$ can be chosen globally (on the entire space) without worrying about violating the original (nonlinearized) constraints.
To highlight the "advantage", SQP linearizes the entire constraint $f_i - g_i$, so the solution to the SQP subproblem cannot guarantee feasibility. It has to be combined with line search or trust region techniques, while using line search for CCP is optional.
The authors say that using line search for CCP "may lead to faster convergence". I think what they meant is that the convex subproblem is rarely solved exactly (step 2 of Basic CPP in the paper), but instead it is terminated after a few iterations of the convex subproblem solver, and then it may be beneficial to apply line search to improve the solution as it is usually quite cheap computationally compared to a single iteration of the convex subproblem solver.

Thank you I have up vote your  answer
